# How to use GloVe to generate vector matrix?

Tags: python, vectorization, tf-idf, hdbscan

I am using [HDBSCAN](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan) algorithm to create clusters from the documents I have. But to create a vector matrix from the words, I am using [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) algorithm and want to use [GloVe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GloVe_(machine_learning)). I have searched posts but could not understand how to use this algorithm.  I also read about [Gensim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gensim) but did not understand how could I use this to implement `GloVe`. Here is what I am doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import re
import os
import codecs
from sklearn import feature_extraction
import mpld3
import csv
import string
import time
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import hdbscan

csvRows = []
nltk.download('stopwords')

title = []
synopses = []
filename = "twitter-test-dataset.csv"
num_clusters = 10
pkl_file = "doc_cluster.pkl"
generate_pkl = False

# pre-process data
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv reader object
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    # extracting field names through first row
    fields = csvreader.next()

    # extracting each data row one by one
    duplicates = 0
    for row in csvreader:
        # removes the characters specified
        line = re.sub(r'[.,"!]+', '', row[2], flags=re.MULTILINE)
        line = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # removes RT
        line = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '',
                    line, flags=re.MULTILINE)  # remove link
        line = re.sub(r'[:]+', '', line, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        line = (re.sub(
            "(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", line, flags=re.MULTILINE))
        line = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable,
                    line)  # filter non-ascii characers
        if line not in synopses:
            synopses.append(line)
            title.append(row[2])
        else:
            duplicates += 1

print("Removed " + str(duplicates) + " rows")


stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")


def tokenize_and_stem(text):
    # first tokenize by sentence, then by word to ensure that punctuation is caught as it's own token
    tokens = [word for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(
        text) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
    filtered_tokens = []
    # filter out any tokens not containing letters (e.g., numeric tokens, raw punctuation)
    for token in tokens:
        if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
            filtered_tokens.append(token)
    stems = [stemmer.stem(t) for t in filtered_tokens]
    return stems


def tokenize_only(text):
    # first tokenize by sentence, then by word to ensure that punctuation is caught as it's own token
    tokens = [word.lower() for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
            for word in nltk.word_tokenize(sent)]
    filtered_tokens = []
    # filter out any tokens not containing letters (e.g., numeric tokens, raw punctuation)
    for token in tokens:
        if re.search('[a-zA-Z]', token):
            filtered_tokens.append(token)
    return filtered_tokens


totalvocab_stemmed = []
totalvocab_tokenized = []

for i in synopses:
    # for each item in 'synopses', tokenize/stem
    allwords_stemmed = tokenize_and_stem(i)
    # extend the 'totalvocab_stemmed' list
    totalvocab_stemmed.extend(allwords_stemmed)

    allwords_tokenized = tokenize_only(i)
    totalvocab_tokenized.extend(allwords_tokenized)

vocab_frame = pd.DataFrame(
    {'words': totalvocab_tokenized}, index=totalvocab_stemmed)

# print "there are " + str(vocab_frame.shape[0]) + " items in vocab_frame"


# define vectorizer parameters
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                                min_df=0.0, stop_words='english',
                                use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, ngram_range=(1, 3))

#CREATE TFIDF MATRIX
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(synopses)
terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()


c = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=5)
#PASS TFIDF_MATRIX TO HDBSCAN
c.fit(tfidf_matrix)
print(c.labels_)
sys.exit()
```

As you could see in the above implementation, I have used `HDBSCAN` along with `tf-idf` for text clustering. How could I use `GloVe` in place of `tf-idf`?

Answer (score 0):

The usual thing seems to be to use the average of all glove vectors for each word in the document.

I'm not convinced by this. The theoretical support seems to be fragile that you can actually add or average these vectors, as this breaks angles.